# Why can't you use function in write context in computer programming?

Tags: javascript, php, function, return, computer-science

Please consider the following code in javascript:

```
var y = 786;
var x = function(){
    console.log(y);
    return y;
}

x() = "new value for y"; //gives error
```

Similarly in php:

```
function x(){
    static $y = 786;
    echo $y . "</br>";
    return $y;
}

x() = "new value for $y"; //gives error
```

So, is it is a general rule in every programming language? Why wouldn't the statement `x() = "new y"` just execute `x()` and then after the function executes all its contents, just assign `new y` to variable `y`?

Comment: because `x()` isn't an lvalue.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Isn't `x()` same as `y`?

Comment: And what do you do for `function f() { return 4; }; f() = 5;`? Also, while `x() === y`, it doesn't mean, that "y is x()" in the sense you are talking about.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you think/want the result to be.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ok, but what if I forcefully define a function to return reference to a variable? I need a different question, I think. I was trying to do `func(){return &y}` so that I could do `func() = "new value"`

Comment: well, you could make a language that does that, but javascript doesn't, and it also doesn't sound like the benefits would outweigh the costs. Why don't you just do `y = { v: 786 }; function f() { return y; }; f().v = "new value";`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yeah, I know. That's what I was thinking. I think in js you can't return by reference; contrary to php. So we'll have to bind the variable as object property which is immutable.

Comment: As written above, you can always just return a reference to an object, and modify said object. It behaves very similarly.

Answer (score 3):

`x()` is evaluated to 786, as that is what's returned from the function. The final line of the function therefore will come compile to something like `786 = "new value for $y"`. This is not valid code, as you can't assign a value (the string "new value for $y") to another value (786).

You can assign a value to a ***variable*** however. If your aim is to store the value returned by the function `x` in the variable `y` then you want to write something like 
`y = x()`

Hope this makes sense/answers your question